# Filter the data from mutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have the following `sharedInstance`, and I am currently working on `sharedData.allComboItems`.

I wonder how could able to find the `ComboItem` where `eachComboItem` equals `main`.

The following approach did not work.

```
NSPredicate *comboItemPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eachComboItem == [c]", @"main"];
NSArray *mainItems = [sharedData.allComboItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:comboItemPredicate];
```

[image]

Comment: You meant `@"eachComboItem ==[c] %@", @"main"`?

Comment: @Larme yes, that is what I meant. I have tried your suggestion but it returns me `0` item.

Comment: can you post the content of `sharedData.allComboItems`??

Comment: Seems your `allComboItems` is a 2-dimensional array (array of arrays), this might explain why your filtering predicate doesn't work.